# Child class variable referring Parent class object

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, polymorphism

Below is the syntax, using TypeScript,

```
interface Animal{
    eat():void;
    sleep():void;
}

class Mammal implements Animal{

    constructor(private name:string){
        console.log(this.name, "is alive");
    }

    eat(){
        console.log("Like a mammal");
    }

    sleep(){
        console.log("Like a mammal");
    }
}

class Dog extends Mammal{
    eat(){
        console.log("Like a dog")
    }
}

let m: Mammal = new Dog("Prisca"); // looks fine
let d: Dog = new Mammal("abomination"); // This also works
```

For variable `d`, TypeScript supports Structural typing and type `Dog` has atleast properties(similar) that `Mammal` has, after overriding. So variable `d` can still point to `Mammal` type object until one more property is added in `Dog` type.

In TypeScript, How to avoid such pitfalls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to avoid it. Structural typing is a need in TypeScript for interoperability with JavaScript and JSON. Is a little price we've got to pay, and a consquence of TypeScript purpose, which is to add types to JavaScript while still being completely compatible with it and, especially, with existent codebase.

The only way to avoid it, in your example, would be to add something to `Dog` that `Mammal` does not have, or, maybe, to make `Mammal` an abstract class, so it can't be directly instantiated. In this case it would be logical, as you might create a new `Dog`, `Cat`, `Horse` ... but not just a new `Mammal`.

As pointed by Titian and Estus, an easy option if you don't want to make `Mammal` abstract and want to go the way of differentiating the classes even if you don't really want to add anything extra, would be to add an irrelevant private property without (almost) any effect at runtime:

```
private isDog: undefined;
```

Comment: You mean, the reason TypeScript introduced Structural typing is for interoperability with javascript libraries?

Comment: Privates are usually a good way to ensure type incompatibility. Adding `private isDog: true` to `Dog` will ensure nothing except classes derived from `Dog` are assignable to a variable of type `Dog`

Comment: Not exactly, is just to be able to extract types from common scenarios in JavaScript, like defining objects on the go, without constructor functions. It allows for a let of errors to be caught this way. Of course there are pifalls, like the one you post, but the advantages are many more than the disadvantages.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir More specifically, `private isDog: undefined`, to be compatible with strict mode. I guess this should be the answer here.

Comment: @estus true, that would work better since at run-time accessing the property will actually yeild undefined. While not explicitly stated the last paragraph basically is this idea of adding something extra. maybe oscar can add this note to the answer?

Comment: Added. Thank you guys.

Comment: We know the reason, why `d` is able to store `Mammal` type object, but, are we not breaking the purpose of `extends` keyword?

Comment: Well, what `extends` means when you do `Dog extends Mammal` is that every dog is a mammal. That is expressed, and it is true. The fact that `d: Dog` can store a `Mammal` object perverts, in a way, this? Maybe yes. Of course no pure OO language allows this, but JavaScript (and by extension TypeScript) are not pure object-oriented languages. When designing TypeScript, I suppose that the team behind it had to decide, in lots of questions, between what is correct (for an OOP language), and what is most useful. I think the usefulness won most of the time, but I think it is a good thing.